# How to query based on an association not having a specific value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Lets say I have 2 models:

```
class User
has_many :books
end

class Book
belongs to :user
end
```

and let's say that book has only one field: Title.

How do I query for the users that dont have a book with title "abc"???

I tried the following:

```
User.left_outer_joins(:books).group("users.id, books.title").having("COUNT(books.title) = 0 or books.title != #{title}")
```

The problem with this query is that if the user has 2 books ("abc" and "xyz") it will still return it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `User.joins(:books).merge(Book.where.not(title: 'abc'))`

Comment: So you want to say that if any user has even a single booked named 'abc' in his collection his name should not be there in the result, is my understanding correct?

Comment: exactly. I dont want any user that has a book called abc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work

```
User.joins(:books).group('books.user_id')
.having("SUM(IF(books.title = 'abc',1,0)) = ?", 0)
```

Which basically gets only users having zero books with title 'abc'.

Comment: This worked almost right but you were the closest one :)

Comment: The solution is replacing joins with left_outer_join:  User.left_outer_joins(:books).group('books.user_id').having("SUM(IF(books.title = 'abc',1,0)) = ?", 0)

Comment: Otherwise, you dont get the users that dont have any books.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
User.joins(:book).where("books.title !=?","#{title}")
```

Generated query can be viewed in `rails console` as

```
User.joins(:book).where("books.title !=?","#{title}").explain
```

[See the Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe easiest way is:

- With uniq title in books

  ```
  book = Book.where(title: 'abc').first
  user_id = book.user.id
  User.where.not(id: user_id)
  ```
- Without uniq title in books

  ```
  books = Book.where(title: 'abc')
  users_ids = books.map { |b| b.user.id }
  User.where.not(id: users_ids)
  ```
- If you want do with group and having, then you need a sql like

  ```
  select  users.id, IF(title = 'abc',1,0) has_book
  from    users
          left join books b on user_id = users.id
  group by id
  having sum(has_book) = 0
  ```

  with AR

  ```
  User.left_outer_joins(:books).
       select("*, IF(books.title = 'abc',1,0) has_book").
       group(:id).having("sum(has_book) = 0")
  ```

I hope it is useful :)